# Unable to revert or restore changes in a folder mapped to a different Volume (macOS)

Tags: tfs

There's a problem with TFS everywhere plugin for Eclipse if I try to revert or restore a file under a source control and if the folder/file is mapped to a different volume than the actual project.

When I try to restore or revert it, I get an error:

`java.io.IOException: Failed to rename /Users/*/*/*/*/.tf1/8/d54f18aa-bdce-4ab7-958a-01eaaf0c36c1.tmp to /Volumes/macOSData/*/*/*/*/*/some_file.cs. Check the file and directory permissions.`

Log has additional line:

`2018-07-31 12:44:39,814 WARN [ModalContext] (com.microsoft.tfs.util.FileHelpers) Main rename failed (source permissions problem?), trying to rename temp file back`

There's no problem while I get specific version of the project, even with overriding existing files, so there permissions are fine, at least for getting files. Also, this does not happen when the file is on the same volume as the local TFS mapping.

Setting all permissions to 777 does fix the problem, but this marks all files with +x making them all "changed", making this solution unacceptable.

I tried mapping the base folder to a second drive (i.e. force creating a *.tf* folder on a second drive), but this doesn't help. The error will appear when I try to revert stuff on the main volume.

I tried using symlinks so the mapping stays within the same volume, but still no luck.

Is there any way to solve this? Or everything should be on the same volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a whole day of digging around and poking with `jshell`, this appears to be a bug with `File.renameTo()` in Java on macOS. `renameTo` function silently fails without any exception even though there's no permission issue to write to the destination. This happens only when writing to a different volume.

I have submitted a pull request into TFS Everywhere repo on github with a workaround for this issue.

Anyone interested can compile plugin with this changes to get things working:
https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/pull/276